# Graphing Differential Equations and ListPlot on the same axes?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm working on a simulation where I've got a list of points (i.e. {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, ... , {10, 10}}). I'm trying to graph a differential equation on the same axes as the list of points. I know I have to Plot NDSolve to plot the differential equation and ListPlot on the list of points. How would I do both?

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time, share complete information (DE's and data points).

Are you looking for something like this?

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 1}];

p1 = Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}];

points = Table[{t, N@Exp[t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.5}];

p2 = ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or just add the points to the `Plot` using`Epilog`, e.g., `Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[points]}]`